# Autocomplete in jQuery UI works slowly. How to inform user that a work is being done under the hood?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

jQuery UI 1.12.1

In html I have an input tag. A user inputs some code. And then I use jQuery UI to organize autocompletion.

My code:

```
function select_autocomplete_variant() {
    $("#user_input").autocomplete({
        minLength: 1,
        source: get_array_for_autocomplete(),
    });
}
```

The problem is that arrays for autocomplete are rather big. This code hangs for about a couple of seconds every time a user enters another symbol. This itself is not a problem: user will wait. But the problem is that the user is unaware that the progrm is working for him while he is waiting.

Is it possible to show a spinning cursor to the user while autocomplete is working.

Comment: Please include a complete example. What is `get_array_for_autocomplete()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you expect that results will 'take a long time' you may consider adjusting the `minLength` to a higher value.

You can also use function for Source, allowing you to execute your own AJAX call. This gives you the ability to start and stop a GIF or present a notification. Example:

```
function select_autocomplete_variant() {
    $("#user_input").autocomplete({
        minLength: 1,
        source: function(req, resp){
          var $el = $(".ui-autocomplete-input", this);
          $.ajax({
            url: 'mySearch.php',
            data: { term: req.term },
            beforeSend: function(){
              $el.addClass("ui-autocomplete-loading");
            },
            success: function(data){
              $el.removeClass("ui-autocomplete-loading");
              resp(data)
            }
          });
        }
    });
}
```

See more under Theming for http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Hope that helps.